# A Regal Riley Riddle

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

Of the mob, my prefix is head
In a short time, my infix, dead
A game with friends is my suffix
A country I will try to fix

(This Riley uses homophones)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you

> DONALD TRUMP?

Of the mob, my prefix is head

> The DON is the mob’s leader.

In a short time, my infix, dead

> You might be very OLD.

A game with friends is my suffix

> You can play a game of TRUMP with friends.

A country I will try to fix

> *A reference to Making America Great Again?*

Comment: I'll wait to see you edit your post to include the solution before I say if you're right or wrong ;)

Comment: How does this look, @Ertai87?

Comment: You have the correct answer, but the infix is wrong.  As a hint, think of a word that ends with a D.

Comment: How about this infix, @Ertai87?

Comment: Yup, that's the one.